# WPF Image styles DataTrigger binding not working on change?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have the following datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PluginItems}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" x:Name="dtg_Plugins" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="315" Width="446" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" Padding="0" RowHeight="26">
```

And it contains column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserResize="False" CanUserReorder="False" Width="26">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="btn_PluginPlay" Padding="0" Height="26" Style="{StaticResource MetroFlatButton}" Background="Transparent" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Click="btn_PluginPlay_Click">
                                <Image Width="26" Height="26">
                                    <Image.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource PlayIcon}"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRunning, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource PlayIcon}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRunning, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource StopIcon}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Image.Style>
                                </Image>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I'm not sure why but the DataTrigger to change the image as shown, doesn't work.
The ItemsSource is ObservableCollection, the rest works just fine.

What could be the cause for this?

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the DataTrigger Bindings is pointless. It has no effect.

Comment: That said, here's the standard stupid question: you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and you are firing the PropertyChanged event when the IsRunning property changes?

Comment: Thanks! And I have implemented yep that's why it makes no sense :(

Comment: It displays PlayIcon, but not StopIcon when IsRunning is true? Your MetroFlatButton Style doesn't somehow bend the DataContext property? And IsRunning is a *public* property? Why do I have to ask all this? Show *all the relevant* parts of your code please.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a single `DataTrigger`:

```
<Button x:Name="btn_PluginPlay" Padding="0" Height="26" Style="{StaticResource MetroFlatButton}" 
        Background="Transparent" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
        Click="btn_PluginPlay_Click">
    <Image Width="26" Height="26">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource PlayIcon}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRunning}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource StopIcon}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

Then it should work provided that the `PluginItem` class, or whatever you call it, has a public `bool` property called `IsRunning` that raises change notifications whenever it's set to a new value.